# MySQL Auto Generated Unique Text Value?

Tags: mysql

I have a `MySQL` table that looks like this:

`my_number`       `my_unique_text_field`

in which, `my_number` is an integer

Whenever I insert a number to field `my_number`, I'd like a unique text value to be assigned to field `my_unique_text_field`. Is it possible to achieve this using `MySQL` directly? or must I generate this unique text string using my client (I am using `python`)?

Comment: Do you need this unique text to be meaningful?? You might consider using hashes/UUID if that is not the case..

Comment: No, the unique text should not be meaningful -- it should only be unique

Comment: You can put a Unique constraint on your `my_unique_field` column in MySQL. Every new duplicate addition would fail. But, this sort of doesnt fits your idea of auto generation? right?

Comment: Right. So best would still be to generate this unique ID using my `python` client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysql's [UUID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) is good enough. But in case if you still worry about possible duplicates - you'd better generate it in python and handle unique constraint error.

Comment: Thanks. Can there be duplicates with `MySQL` generated `UUID`?

Comment: @user540009: by definition and description - nope: `A UUID is designed as a number that is globally unique in space and time. Two calls to UUID() are expected to generate two different values, even if these calls are performed on two separate computers that are not connected to each other.`. So it is unique in our universe.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just after a unique id and not Text, your best bet is using UUID

Comment: Thank you. If one is after a unique id, and one can choose either a text id or a numerical id, is there a preference?

Comment: An UUID is a mixture of alphabets and numbers - So, there's no options. Generally speaking, i believe numerical id's are more easier to manage. UUID's can be used when you have security concerns. Example: Say you want to generate invitation URL's for your Users Invites, it's a better idea to use UUID over numerical ids since Numerical Ids can be easily guessed and Invites could be compromised..(If you dont have a solid logic in your application.)